# Parse cloud code & triggers perfomance - usage

Tags: performance, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I recently started working with cloud code for my social iOS app, in my Parse Server which is deployed in a Digital Ocean droplet.

Now, what I want to know is, whether using too much cloud functions instead of native swift, is good practise or not. So far, i'm using cloud functions for liking/unliking photos, posting/deleting comments and following/unfollowing people. Now, I'm considering to put the feed content retrieval into the cloud as well.

In addition I'm using some triggers too. For example when a photo is deleted, it goes in the "afterDelete" function and deletes all notifications/likes/comments associated to that photo.

So, that's what I want to know. Should I reduce the amount of cloud code I'm using, or maximise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the server do the heavy things, bro.

I am using Cloud code for almost every function of my app.

AFAIK, trigger doesn't affect the performance and using cloud code is a very good practice.

You don't need to give update for your logical changes.
More work on server, less work on mobile.

IMHO, maximize the use of cloud code.

You might want to check this [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/pa4373/parse-cloud-code)

Comment: Just a thought a had... In the "afterDelete" function that I mentioned above, where it deletes all notifications/likes/comments associated to the deleted photo... What if there are say, 1 million likes and 55 thousand comments, what happens then?

Comment: If the server needs to do heavier work, you'll need get a better server at that time. Sever doesn't have to do extra work because you use `afterDelete`. It just does what you want it to do in `afterDelete`. If you want the server to do heavier jobs then you will need a server that is capable of doing your jobs.